# How to match on a tree of arrow association (`x->y`) in Scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-quasiquotes

I would like to pattern match for the tree of the `x -> y` operation in Scala macros. I am cross compiling against Scala 2.10.4 (with [Macro Paradise](https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise)) and Scala 2.11.x. I have tried the following patterns and none worked:

```
arrowTree match {
  case q"$x -> $y"                                            => ???
  case q"scala.Predef.ArrowAssoc[${_}, ${_}]($x).->$y"        => ???
  case q"_root_.scala.Predef.ArrowAssoc[${_}, ${_}]($x).->$y" => ???
  case q"_root_.scala.Predef.ArrowAssoc($x).->$y"             => ???
}
```

What patterns would make this match work for both 2.10.4 and 2.11.x?

Comment: what is `q`? I've only ever seen `s`, `f`, and `raw` for string interpolation... so what's `q`?

Comment: quasiquotes, its used to create a Tree from a string

Comment: what about `q"$x -> $y"`? you're not assigning any variables in your quasiquotes and they're incorrect.

Comment: Thanks I have added $ in front of x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a perfect world you'd definitely expect first one to match but it's not that simple.

Whenever you write `foo -> bar` in Scala you effectively calling a method like `foo.->(bar)`. When typechecker tries to find a method called `->` it fails and starts looking for any implicits that could have added that method to foo and it usually finds a `Predef.ArrowAssoc` which turns original expression into `scala.this.Predef.ArrowAssoc[Int](1).->[Int](2)`.

To match this you can use following pattern:

```
case q"scala.this.Predef.ArrowAssoc[$_]($foo).->[$_]($bar)" =>
```

Here we put wildcards in a type parameter position as we don't care about those at the moment.

On 2.10 the pattern would be slightly different because implicit was named differently back then:

```
case q"scala.this.Predef.any2ArrowAssoc[${_}]($foo).->[${_}]($bar)" =>
```

Another difference here is need to use curly braces around wildcards. `$_` syntax in string interpolators isn't supported on 2.10.